# Where to Configure webpack to load an alternate less file and scope global styles

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to introduce my global style with ant design theme.
from antd doc https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme
its said to Configure webpack to load an alternate less file and scope global styles

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin( /node_modules\/antd\/lib\/style\/index\.less/, path.resolve(rootDir, 'src/myStylesReplacement.less') )

#antd { @import '~antd/lib/style/core/index.less'; @import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less'; }
```

where should i configure it? has web pack been install with antd? or should i place the code in config-overrides.js ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I managed to fixed it like this:

1. Create a **myStylesReplacement.less** file in your src folder with the following content:

   - `#antd { @import '~antd/lib/style/core/index.less'; @import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less'; }`
2. Edit your **webpack.config.js** file  and add:

   - at the top of the file add `const webpack = require('webpack'); const path =  require('path')`
   - in the plugins list add `new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin( /node_modules\/antd\/lib\/style\/index\.less/, path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/myStylesReplacement.less') )`
3. Import `antd/lib/style/index.less` in your app

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import ant less styles need to add config file `.babelrc` and `postcss.config.js`.

> .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }] // `style: true` for less
    ]
}
```

> postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
};
```

> webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

require("babel-core/register");
require("babel-polyfill");

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.jsx'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/, // remove if not use scss styles
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader:'css-loader'
                    }, {
                        loader:'sass-loader'
                    }, {
                        loader:'postcss-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader:'css-loader'
                    }, {
                        loader:'sass-loader'
                    }, {
                        loader:'postcss-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                        options: {
                            babel: false,
                            icon: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist', // update with the project directory
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist', // update with the project directory
        disableHostCheck: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: { 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    }
};
```